# How to get text of hyperlink which is in grid-view and send that text to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My scenario is from my database I fetch story data n title and displayed in gridview now title is hyperlink when user click on any link then the text of hyper link send to reader page and story is fetch from database through title text. How can I do this please help me..

Comment: when you click on any link, please explain??

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? DR1.GetValue(0).ToString(); has value while debugging? EDIT: Also str = ? when page load?

Comment: Can you paste your code of gridveiw for answer?

Comment: see forget about my code its an experiment i want the scenario which i describe. and when any reader opens the page all titles in gridview is displayed now user clicks on the title link.

Comment: i am a beginner so i dnt know hoe to implement this can u send me the related code or links.

Comment: Check my answer, i think this exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="storyid" DataSourceID="yourdatasource">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="StoryData" HeaderText="StoryData" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StoryData" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>




<script runat="server">
    void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
            link.Text = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            link.NavigateUrl = @"ReaderPage.aspx?StoryTitle=" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            link.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='red'");
            link.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#E9EDF1'");
            link.Target = "_blank";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(link);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: @WellCome gald it helped